# Cluster adjacency matrix of different sizes

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis, data-mining, adjacency-matrix

I have created adjacency matrix for directed graphs of different sizes. I have around 30,000 matrices, each on a separate text file. How can I cluster them, is there any tools available. What is the best way to represent a directed graph for clustering.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you want to achieve? Group similar matrices, right?
With k-means, you will not have much fun here. The adjacency matrices are binary; interpreting them as huge vectors and computing an L-p-norm distance (e.g. Euclidean distance) on them, then computing *average* matrixes - which is what k-means does - doesn't sound sensible to me. Plus, you will likely be bitten by the *curse of dimensionality*. The high number of dimensions will make all matrixes appear similar.

For pretty much any clustering algorithm, the first question *you* as the "domain expert" will have to answer is: **what makes two adjacency matrixes similar?** Once you have formalized this, you will be able to run many clustering algorithms, including classic single-link clustering, DBSCAN or OPTICS.

Answer (score 1):

I would try k-means and voronoi-diagrams. It can be by computed with a minimal spanning tree and by looking for the longest edges. Then you can compute the different cluster with the traditional k-means using the mst edges as center. Another possiblity would be a hierarchical cluster for example a space-filling-curve. See for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/visualization-software-for-clustering.

Comment: I think he is not trying to cluster nodes/edges, but to cluster groups of graphs.

Comment: @cyborg: I think he wants to stack them.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some ideas for graph features/statistics here:
http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.html